# GCC ASM set AH Register to 1h from C

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

is there a way to push this line to asm from C from GCC

```
    mov ah,1h
    int 21h
```

I can't find a way to set the AH register to 1h

```
 asm("mov %ah,1h");
 asm("int 21h");
```

Comment: Since that seems to be code for DOS and it's unlikely you are using a 16 bit gcc so it probably won't work even if it compiles. (You did not specify your environment, unfortunately.) Not to mention that int 21/01 is keyboard input so you normally want a way to return the key for which you'd need to use extended asm.

Comment: I'm trying to run the program from grub. intel x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1h` means `1` in hexadecimal number. You can use `$0x1` to express that. (`$` is required for integer literals in GCC assembly language and `0x` is marking the number as hexadecimal).

Also note that in GCC assembly language, the destination of `mov` instruction (and other instructions with two operands) should be the 2nd operand.

```
asm("mov $0x1, %ah");
asm("int $0x21");
```

One more note is that if you want to make sure that `%ah` is `0x1` when the `int` is executed, the two lines should be put into one `asm` statement not to let the compiler put other instructions between them.

```
asm(
    "mov $0x1, %ah\n\t"
    "int $0x21"
);
```

Comment: These two instructions must be within a single asm statement to ensure that ah doesn’t get changed in between them. Also the instruction to assign al to an output must be part of the same asm statement.

Comment: `$ is required for integer literals in GCC assembly language` you can use `.intel_syntax noprefix` and then use the integer literal without `$`

Comment: Also note that a clobber is in order to make sure gcc doesn't hold anything in ah.